# Hidden attribute on content type

Tags: content-type

What's the use of hidden attribute on content types? I set a content type to be Hidden, it doesn't not show in the New list, but when I set it as default content content type, and click add new item, I can create an item from this content type. So how that's hidden?

Comment: How are you setting it to hidden? You can configure a Content Type at the Site Level, then override at the List Level. That may be what is happening.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be hidden if you set it as the default?

Comment: Hidden = don't show it in new. Default=the default when user presses new. These two can coincide.

Comment: Thanks Xristosk, that explains my question. @John, it was just confusing me.